# Windows Azure SQL database. Sharding Complete Tables to limit DB Size

Tags: azure-sql-database, sharding

I am moving my web app from on-premise to windows azure. In my app, I have two DBs which are setup on same SQL Server and so I can query one database from the other easily using fully qualified name in my query. Now moving to cloud, I am facing limitation where I can't query tables in One DB from another DB. I can't change my queries because it requires a complete change in web app. I was thinking to merge these DBs into one to save the web app rewrite. But my DBs are huge(40 GB each) and have heavy load(millions of hits per day). 
Now my question is,

- Windows Azure SQL database is good enough to handle this number of
  hits and huge DBs?
- Is it a good idea to merge two huge DBs into one? Here I was thinking
  to shard all tables in the second db so that all the data will be
  saved in second instance.
- What else I can do?

Sorry If problem is vague and unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You also have the option of not using SQLAzure and use the new Azure IAAS where you can spin up a SQL Server instance that is closer to more traditional SQL Server. You can also control the instance size more easily this way. Here is some info http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/04/24/sql-server-in-windows-azure-infrastructure-services-updated-documentation-and-best-practices-for-ga-upcoming-blogs.aspx

Comment: Seems good solution. But there is another factor involved and that is cost. My client is not ready to bear high cost.

Comment: Fair enough, although if you use SQL Server there always is a cost. If you already have licenses I think it is possible to transfer them to Azure IAAS

Comment: My client said they have challenges in the license. Don't know what challenges exactly are, but they are not willing to move licensed DB on cloud.